# VS2008 trying to create a new project from pre-existing C++ code on a mapped network drive

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mapped-drive

I have a bunch of source code checked out from a SVN repository, now living in a folder on a mapped network drive which happens to be a linux machine. We're using this as a build environment as it currently has the numerous libraries needed to build painlessly.

What I want to do is use VS2008 on my Windows Xp development box, and create a new project linked to this source folder, so that I can explore and edit the source with the benefits of intellisense, then simply Putty into the mounted directory and run "make".

However, when coming to create a "New project from Existing Code" in Vs2008, all the mapped network drives on my system don't show up. If I then try and open a project though, the drives are suddenly visible in the Open dialog browser.

I've heard that VS2008 doesn't like giving permissions to network drives, and I've run a command recommended elsewhere for opening permissions, but to no effect.

```
caspol -q -machine -addgroup 1.2 -url file://H:/* FullTrust
```

The mapped drives still aren't visible when trying to import from existing code, or when trying to starta new project based on the network drives.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the solution was to enter the full location of the network drive, (even though it wasn't visible in the file browser) into the Folder Name box. Also, the command above needed to be tweaked to be

`caspol -q -machine -addgroup 1.2 -url file://networkname/codestorage/* FullTrust`

After that, the full folder was loaded into VS2008, and we were able to edit it properly. Quite why it doesn't use the same dialog box as "Open Project" though I don't know!